# Removing commas from a list and just keeping the elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list. I want to remove all commas and just be left with the elements of the set.

```
Tuples[{I, l}, 16]

{{I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I}, {I, I, I, I, I, I,
      I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, l}, {I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I,
      I, I, l, I}, {I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, I, l, l}, ....}
```

I would like something like:

```
{{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIl}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIlI}, {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIll}, ....}
```

Comment: Can you show us what kind of final result you expect?

Comment: @rafalc sure, please look at edited question

Comment: While it can be answered it appears to be a very strange request. Why do you need a **symbol** composed of 16 `I-s`? Maybe knowing the context we could help to solve your initial problem.

Comment: does `ToExpression /@ (StringRiffle[# , {"{", "", "}"}] & /@ 
   Tuples[ToString /@ {I, l}, 16])` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr I haven't checked since I got the solution from Henrik, yours probably will work too but he beat you to it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want?

```
ToExpression[StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, Tuples[{I, l}, 16], {2}]]
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do:

```
Symbol @* StringJoin /@ Tuples[{"I", "l"}, 16] 

% // Short
```

> {IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII, IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIl, IIIIIIIIIIIIIIlI, 
>   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIll, << 65528 >>, llllllllllllllII, llllllllllllllIl, lllllllllllllllI, 
>   llllllllllllllll}